# Why is IEnumerable losing updated data?

Tags: c#, linq

Could you explain to me why after executing the following code the `Selected` property is not updated to `true`?

The `ListItem` type used comes from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace and is a class (not a struct.) I believed the `FirstOrDefault` function returns a reference to an instance which I can update and pass around in the `items` enumerable.

```
// produce list items out of the communities
IEnumerable<ListItem> items = communities.Select(community => new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString()));

// mark the right list item as selected, if needed
if (platform.CommunityId > 0)
{
    string strCommunityId = platform.CommunityId.ToString();
    ListItem selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == strCommunityId);
    if (selectedItem != null) selectedItem.Selected = true;
}

// now items do not store any updated item!
```

Is that because the enumerator is executed each time a `foreach` is called and thus creating new items instead of returning the set containing the item I updated?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `IEnumerable` is **not repeatable**. You are performing the projection (`community => new ListItem`) *every time it is enumerated* - hence it is a new `ListItem` each time. `Select` is a non-buffered deferred projection.

You can fix everything here with the simple addition of a `.ToList()` to force the data into a single list;

```
var items = communities.Select(
    community => new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString())
).ToList();
```

Now that the data is in the list, you can loop over the *list* any number of times - it'll always be the same items, and changes will be retained.

Answer (score 5):

It happens, because you use `Select`:

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> items = communities
   .Select(community => new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString()));
```

which creates new objects every time you iterate through items.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> items = communities
    .Select(community => new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString()));
```

creates an IEnumerable that's *lazily evaluated* -- that is, every time it is enumerated, the original `communities` sequence is re-enumerated and your `Select` projection is re-executed per item in that sequence.

If you stick a `.ToList()` at the end, changing the line to:

```
IEnumerable<ListItem> items = communities
    .Select(community => new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString()))
    .ToList();
```

you will observe a different result. While it is still an `IEnumerable`, it will no longer be a lazily evaluated one, and the changes you make in it will be observable in later iterations over the same `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

I think Marc Gravell's answer is the right one, but you could avoid this confusion and do it in a single line (possibly leading to another kind of confusion). ;)

```
// produce list items out of the communities
IEnumerable<ListItem> items = communities.Select(community => 
    new ListItem(community.Name, community.Id.ToString()) 
    { 
        Selected = community.Id == platform.CommunityId
    });
```